# NASM GNU/Linux elf: cannot read a floating point number via scanf

Tags: linux, nasm

I am learning NASM and do not have any experience. I have decided to write an app that reads integer and floating point numbers from user input and prints them.

```
;;; File test.asm
;;;
;;; Required packages: nasm, gcc
;;; compile commands:
;;;     nasm -f elf test.asm
;;;     gcc -m32 -o test test.o

%define SYSCALL_EXIT 1 ; system call sys_exit
%define INT32_BYTES_SIZE 4
%define FLOAT32_BYTES_SIZE 4

section .data 
    questionInt32 db "Please enter any integer number.", 0xa, 0x0
    questionFloat32 db "Please enter any decimal number.", 0xa, 0x0

    prompt db "> ", 0x0

    resultMessage db "Entered: int %d, float %e", 0xa, 0x0

    scanAgeFmt db "%d", 0x0
    scanFloatFmt db "%e", 0x0

section .bss 
    inum resb INT32_BYTES_SIZE
    fnum resb FLOAT32_BYTES_SIZE

section .text 
    extern scanf 
    extern printf
    global main 

main:
    call printInt32Prompt
    call scanInt32
    call printFloat32Prompt
    call scanFloat32
    call printMessage
    
    mov eax, SYSCALL_EXIT 
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80 

    ret

scanInt32:
    push inum 
    push scanAgeFmt
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    ret

scanFloat32:
    push fnum 
    push scanFloatFmt
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    ret

printMessage:
    push DWORD [fnum]
    push DWORD [inum]
    push resultMessage
    call printf
    add esp, 12

    ret

printInt32Prompt:
    push questionInt32
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    push prompt
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    ret 

printFloat32Prompt:
    push questionFloat32
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    push prompt
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    ret
```

Reading of integer number works correctly, but I have a problem with floating point one. As you see below, entered value and value from output are different, and I do not have an idea what I have done wrong.

```
$ ./test 
Please enter any integer number.
> 3  
Please enter any decimal number.
> 3.4
Entered: int 3, float 8.104613e+107
```